# Using suppressMessages in rpy2 still prints messages

Tags: rpy2

I'd like to suppress messages from R in rpy2 and thought the following would be enough:

```py
>>> from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr
>>> import rpy2.robjects as robjs

>>> suppmsg = robjs.r["suppressMessages"]
```

but then I get:

```py
>>> suppmsg(robjs.r.message("hello"))
R[write to console]: hello
```

I don't mind the messages during interactive work, but I want them off in a library.  How can they be turned off?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code might not do what you expect to because in R the evaluation of expressions is lazy and in Python it is not.

For example, when doing in R

```
suppressMessages(library("foo"))
```

what happens is that the function `suppressMessages()` is called with the **unevaluated** expression `library("foo")` as an argument. In the body of the function `suppressMessages()` code that turns off the display of messages globally is first run, and then the expression is evaluated, and finally code that restores the display of messages is run.

In Python, doing

```
suppmsg(robjs.r.message("hello"))
```

will first evaluate `robjs.r.message("hello")` (which calls the R function function `message()` through `rpy2`) and the result of this evaluation (what is returned by the function) is passed as an argument to `suppmsg()`.

If you only want to silence import of a library, the function `rpy2.robjects.packages.quiet_require()` can do that for you.

Comment: I understand.  The R messages I'm trying to silence come straight from calls to function `message` as in this example, so this seems inevitable.  It's not the end of the world, but it gets busy when running tests or building a Python package.

Comment: There should be a way to work something out with the R function `sink()` (using `type="message"`).